# A-Frame+Vue: can't bind "visible" attribute of a a-box

Tags: vue.js, aframe

I wanted to see how easily A-Frame and Vue can work together. 
One of the example I met with a google search is this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/baruog/23sdtzgx/

But I didn't like the fact that, to change the properties of the a-box in the example, the functions needed to access the DOM.
Like, for example, in this function:

```
setBoxColor: function(color) {
      document.querySelector('a-box').setAttribute('color', color)
    },
```

So, I wondered, can I bind the attributes of the a-box and change them without accessing to the DOM?

And I changed the code as in this other fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fy83wr49/
that I copy below:

The HTML

```
<div id="vue-app"> 
  <a-scene embedded>
    <a-sky color="#000"></a-sky>
    <a-entity camera look-controls wasd-controls position="0 1 3" rotation="-15 0 0"></a-entity>
    <a-box v-bind:color="color_box" v-bind:opacity="op_box" v-bind:visible="v_box"></a-box>
  </a-scene>
  <p>Click a button to change the color of the box</p>
  <div>
    <button @click="setBoxColor('red')">Red</button>
    <button @click="setBoxColor('blue')">Blue</button>
    <button @click="setBoxColor('green')">Green</button>
    <button @click="setVisibility(true)">True</button>
    <button @click="setVisibility(false)">Flase</button>
    <button @click="changeOpacity()">Opacity</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

And the JS

```
Vue.config.ignoredElements = ['a-scene', 'a-sky'];

var colorButtons = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-app',
  data: {
    color_box: "magenta",
    v_box: false,
    op_box: 0.5,
  },
  methods: {
    setBoxColor: function(color) {
      this.color_box = color;
    },
    setVisibility: function(isVisible) {
      this.v_box = isVisible;
      //document.querySelector('a-box').setAttribute('visible', isVisible)
    },
    changeOpacity: function() {
      this.op_box += 0.1;
      if (this.op_box > 1.0) this.op_box = 0.0;
    }
  }
})
```

What happens is that both the "color" binding and the "opacity" binding work properly, but the "visible" binding doesn't.

Initially I thought that maybe the bindings were supposed to work only with standard html attributes, and it working with the "color" attribute of the a-box was just a coincidence caused by a name collision.
But then I checked the html attributes list here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes and "opacity" isn't listed, so I had to abandon that explanation.

Does anyone have an idea of the reasons that make only the first two bindings work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a-frame docs: https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/visible.html#updating-visible - it seems that `visible` is a special attribute which needs to be updated using `object3D` or `setAttribute` on the element. Actually they call it 'component' visible - not an attribute, while opacity and color seems to be just an attributes. Simple vue binding seems to not work to 'visible component'.